# Flutter delete top border of showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICFbu.png)
The border in the linked image is marked in orange circles.
There is any way to delete it?

My code is:

```
   showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30.0)),
              color: Colors.white,
             Radius.circular(30.0)),               
              ),   
            child: Container(
              height: 180,
              color: Color(0xFF737373),
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                     ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(30),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: You mean the round border or the grey lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the round borders just delete all the borderRadius that your code have, but if you mean the grey lines above the borders do that:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(         //setting a new shape
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
      top: Radius.circular(30),
    ),
  ),
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(),
        ],
      ),
      height: 180,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Tank you!
it is perfect

Comment: Glad i can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        height: 180,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
              title: Text('Test1'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.message),
              title: Text('Test2'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.mic),
              title: Text('Test3'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```